# How to use uBlock Origin to block the Reddit user avatar hover tooltip?

Tags: ublock-origin

On Reddit, when I hover over the avatars of users in the left edge of comments, I get an annoying tooltip that prevents me from what I really want to do, which is collapse and expand comments.

How to use uBlock Origin to block that?

Comment: also consider using "old" reddit, it is missing most of the misfeatures of this new design...

Comment: @htmlcoderexe It's also missing most of the *good* features of the not quite as new, but still newer than old design. (Awesome username btw)

Answer (score 21):

Open uBlock Origin settings, my filters, and put the following then apply changes

```
reddit.com##[id^="SubredditInfoTooltip--"][id$="hover-id"]
reddit.com##[id*="UserInfoTooltip"][id$="hover-id"]
```

Credit goes to this [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/uBlockOrigin/comments/qy60lj/is_it_possible_with_ublockorigin_to_block_the/).